# User Added Value to HttpContext Request/Response Header being removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

I am having some trouble adding a value to the `Page.Request` & `Page.Response` headers and have the key & value stay/persist through a redirect.

I have an enum tracking code that I want to place in the headers to trace how a user goes through my site prior to their checkout.

I am using this code to add the headers to response and request context.

```
var RequestSessionVariable = context.Request.Headers["SessionTrackingCode"];

if (RequestSessionVariable == null)
{
    context.Response.AddHeader("SessionTrackingCode", ((int)tracker).ToString());
    context.Request.Headers.Add("SessionTrackingCode", ((int)tracker).ToString());
}
else
{
    if(!RequestSessionVariable.Contains(((int)tracker).ToString()))
    {
        RequestSessionVariable += ("," + ((int)tracker).ToString());
        context.Request.Headers["SessionTrackingCode"] = RequestSessionVariable;
        context.Response.Headers["SessionTrackingCode"] = RequestSessionVariable;
    }
}
```

The method call that occurs in `Page_Load` of the necessary controls within the website:

```
trackingcodes.AddPageTrackingCode(TrackingCode.TrackingCodes.ShoppingCart, this.Context);
```

The header `SessionTrackingCode` is their but after a `Response.Redirect("~/value.aspx")` the `RequestSessionVariable` is always null. Is there something that happens on the redirect that will wipe out the headers that I add? Or what am I doing wrong on the addition of the header key and value?

`this` equals:

`public partial class Cart : System.Web.UI.UserControl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers send by client on every request, so any redirect will require client to send headers again.

Unless you are using some special client (not a browser) any special headers will be essentially ignored/lost during requests. Browser only will send known headers (cookies, authentication, referrer) in requests and act on other set of known headers in response (setCookies). You are using custom header that not known to browser so browser will not read in from response nor send it in request.

Your options:

- switch to use cookies for your tracking (same as everyone else)
- use AJAX requests to send/receive custom headers (probably not what you are looking for as urls look like regular GET/POST ones)
- build custom client that will pay attention to your headers (purely theoretical, unless you building some sort of sales terminal no one will install your client to visit your site)

Note: adding headers to request in page code does no make much sense as request will not be send anywhere (it is what come from browser).

Comment: Thanks, I figured I would need to go with Cookies but I was trying to avoid it if possible since they won't always be present.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for cookies, rather than http headers. The browser will not return your custom headers to you, but it will return your cookies.